# Manipulating a list while accounting for different ordering of that list - python 2

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a nested list to which Im making some changes (swaps) but the order of the elements in the nested list can be different and I'd like to account for that and perform the changes/swaps on the different orders as well. The other option is doing the changes/swaps on the changed list separately but id like to avoid that.

The list goes,

```
B=[[[m1,h1], [m1,h1]], [[m2,h2], [m2, h2]], [[m3, h3], [m3, h3]], [[m4, h4], [m4, h4]]]
```

As of now `[[m1, h1], [m1, h1]]` is in the 'first' position, `[[m2,h2], [m2, h2]]` in the 'second', `[[m3, h3], [m3, h3]]` in the 'third' and so on, and the code will do the required swaps to this ordering, but I'd also like it to the swaps on the 24 other possible arrangements/permutations (another one of the 24 would be `B=[[[m1,h1], [m1,h1]], [[m2,h2], [m2, h2]], [[m4, h4], [m4, h4]], [[m3, h3], [m3, h3]]]` where the elements in position 3 and 4 are changed) The code Im wokring with is this,

```
A=[[[[m1,h1], [m1,h1]], [[m2,h2], [m2, h2]], [[m3, h3], [m3, h3]], [[m4, h4], [m4, h4]]]]

for r1 in [0,1]:
    if (r1 == 0):
        A_0=A 
    else:
        for i in range(A)):
            tmp_1=A[i]
            A_1=swap_r1(tmp_1, 0, 1,0,1)
            A.append(A_1)
```

So the code has an A list, inside which is the B list mentioned earlier. r1 refers to one of the changes/swaps and if r1==0 then the change doesn't happen and B the list in A remain unchanged. Other wise, r1 can happen and a swap occurs between specific m's and h's in the B list (Ive defined a swapping function for this, swap_r1()), and the new B list added into A, alongside the unchanged B list.

My question is, is there a way to implement the 24 different ordering that can exist with the internal elements in B into the code, and have their r1==0 and r1==1 outcome added into A as well?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're after with the `r1` part, but the 24 different orderings are `permutations`.  Do:

```
from itertools import permutations
list(permutations(B))
```

to get a list of the 24 differently swapped versions of B.

E.g.:

```
>>> list(permutations(range(4)))
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3, 2), (0, 2, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3, 1), (0, 3, 1, 2), (0, 3, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 3, 2), (1, 2, 0, 3), (1, 2, 3, 0), (1, 3, 0, 2), (1, 3, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1, 3), (2, 0, 3, 1), (2, 1, 0, 3), (2, 1, 3, 0), (2, 3, 0, 1), (2, 3, 1, 0), (3, 0, 1, 2), (3, 0, 2, 1), (3, 1, 0, 2), (3, 1, 2, 0), (3, 2, 0, 1), (3, 2, 1, 0)]
```